# Testing if a grails property is lazy/not initialized?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm, lazy-initialization

I can't seem to test if an object is lazy initialized. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public void testLazy(){
   User lazyUser = User.withCriteria {
      like("userId", 'test')
      fetchMode("preferences", FetchMode.LAZY )
   }.get(0)

   assertFalse( "DOM objects of user were not lazy initialized",   
         GrailsHibernateUtil.isInitialized(lazyUser, "preferences") )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing all right.

Exactly same code piece worked for me - for a collection (of child domain objects) property, `isInitialized()` returned `false` and for a String property - `true`. Maybe `FetchMode.LAZY` is not a guarantee - if you're requesting a simple type, it gets fetched anyway.

What is `preferences`' type?

Comment: It's an object with a proper object graph. Oi. I'm using grails 1.3.6 - what are you using?

Comment: I'm on 1.3.5. What if you enable SQL logging, what queries are in log? What if you try it on collection property too?